# Insert data into device one time in ionic

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have an existing data to be inserted in sqlite. I did as following:

```
var db = null;
function createDatabase($cordovaSQLite){

  if (window.cordova) {
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "test.db" }); 
  }else{
    db = window.openDatabase("test.db", '1.0', 'database', 1024 * 1024 * 100); 
  }

  var classes = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classes (id integer primary key, name text)";

  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, classes);

  var classesQuery = "INSERT INTO classes (name) VALUES 'class1'"
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, classesQuery);
}
```

and I called this function when the application is ready

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
  }
  if(window.StatusBar) {
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
  }

  createDatabase($cordovaSQLite);

});
```

It does insert the data and inserts every time when I refresh browser.

I would like the application to insert the data one time and can use the data stored.

Comment: That is  because everytime you are refreshing $ionicPlatform.ready() runs , Why are you using cordova sqlite over browser ? Over device it will run once

Comment: I used browser for quick testing. In device, it will run once; however, it will insert data again once we reload the app.

Answer (score 0):

So you must define the first time the app runs. Inside app.js, in function

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
```

you should create this (ApplicationInitialRun is a service):

```
if (ApplicationInitialRun.isInitialRun()) {
     ApplicationInitialRun.setInitialRun(false);
 }
```

and in services.js

```
.factory('ApplicationInitialRun', function ($window,ConnectivityMonitor,$ionicPopup) {
return {
  setInitialRun: function (initial) {
      $window.localStorage["initialRun"] = (initial ? "true" : "false");

  },
  isInitialRun: function () {
     var value = $window.localStorage["initialRun"] || "true";
       $window.localStorage['newuser']="new";
       return value == "true";

  }
};
})
```

So, you can call your function inside initial run or as you can see i use $window.localStorage['newuser']="new";. With this i am able to check for example

```
if($window.localStorage['newuser']=="new"){
```

and call functions if the user is new or not (In your case you can check if the value exists in localstorage after you insert with your function).

Hope that helps.